# How do I configure laravel sanctum to authorize other domains and that can be consumed by NuxtJS

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum

I have a Nuxt application as a client and a laravel 9 API, this api is using Laravel-Sanctum, I am having problems connecting my Nuxt application with Laravel because the endpoint that is managing sanctum tells me that I am not authorized, both front and back domains are different, is there a configuration that I am skipping and that is why it does not work? here I share my code with you:

config/cors.php

```
<?php

return [

    'paths' => ['api/*',  'login', 'logout', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'api'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

config/sanctum.php

```
<?php

use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;

return [

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1,https://mango-grass-0b3b8cd10.3.azurestaticapps.net/',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),

    // 'guard' => ['web'],

   'expiration' => null,

    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],

];
```

config/session.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    'encrypt' => false,

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION'),

    'table' => 'sessions',

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE'),

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    'path' => '/',

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN'),

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

    'http_only' => true,

    'same_site' => 'lax',

];
```

config/kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $middleware = [
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        ],
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
auth: {
    redirect: {
      home: '/',
      logout: '/login',
      login: '/login',
    },
    plugins: [
      '~/plugins/auth.js',
      { src: '~/plugins/sweetalert2.js', mode: 'client' },
      { src: '~/plugins/VueDebounce.js' },
    ],
    strategies: {
      laravelSanctum: {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: backendUrl,
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/api/login',
          },
          logout: {
            url: '/api/logout',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

login.vue

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
      if (email.value === '' || password === '') {
        Swal.fire({
          title: '¡Información!',
          text: '¡Existen campos obligatorios vacíos.!',
          icon: 'info',
          confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar',
        })
      } else {
        loaderButton.value = true
        await $auth
          .loginWith('laravelSanctum', {
            data: { email: email.value, password: password.value },
          })
          .then((response) => {
            backendService.value.getMe().then((responseMe) => {
              localStorage.setItem('UserName', responseMe.name)
              localStorage.setItem('UserEmail', responseMe.email)
              localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
              getPermissionRol(responseMe.permission)
              router.push('/')
            })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            if (error.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
              Swal.fire({
                title: '¡Error!',
                text: 'No se puede conectar con el servidor. Verifique su conexión a internet o inténtelo más tarde.',
                icon: 'error',
                confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar',
              })
            } else if (error.request && error.request.message) {
              Swal.fire({
                title: '¡Error!',
                text: error.request.message,
                icon: 'error',
                confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar',
              })
            } else {
              Swal.fire({
                title: '¡Error!',
                text: '¡Error!',
                icon: 'error',
                confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar',
              })
            }
          })
          .finally(() => {
            loaderButton.value = false
          })
      }
```

I would appreciate your help please.

I followed the steps in the documentation about the sanctum configuration, I tried to put the values in the .env file and it didn't work either, it keeps sending me the error "419 unknown status" when I try to login.

Answer (score 0):

set sanctumn.php :

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8080,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),
```

then set env variable in .env file as given below:

```
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
ROOT_URL=//127.0.0.1:8080
APP_URL=http://localhost
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost
```

then run these commands in laravel project:

```
php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan optimize && php artisan serve
```

then in your nuxt login.vue:

```
async function validate() {

  await useFetch("http://localhost:8080/sanctum/csrf-cookie", {
    credentials: "include",
  });

  const token = useCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');

  await useFetch("http://localhost:8080/api/login", {
    credentials: "include",
    method: "POST",
    body: {
      'email': 'email',
      'password': 'password'
    },
    headers: {
      'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token.value as string,
    },
    watch: false
  })
// remaining codes...
}
```